# How to publish a HTML manual with each (sub)sections as a separate page and a front page with TOC?

Tags: org-export, org-publish

I am using `org-publish` to generate a static web site. I have a large org file with many subtrees (max depth 5).

I'd like to be able to generate a site very similar to the [org-mode manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/index.html) where each section is its own page and a TOC front page with links to all the subsections. Is this possible with `org-publish`? I assume the org-mode manual is made with standard org tools??

My basic understanding of `org-publish` is that each `html` page needs its own `.org` file. That would be a nightmare for me to split up by big org file into subfiles (one per subtree) and put them into a nested folder structure. Ugh.... I hope there is a smoother way.

I am aware that `ox-hugo` and other packages exist.... hoping this can be done readily with `org-publish` itself.

The org-mode manual also comes in a [complete version](https://orgmode.org/org.html): 1 html page with everything included, i.e., all sections included in one long web page. I am able to make a single html file like this using `org-export`.

---

After searching, I found the related (if not exact) query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16049709/create-multi-page-website-with-one-org-mode-file). One of the answers points to `makeinfo`(which resonates with @NickD comment below)

Comment: The Org mode manual is produced through the `texinfo` exporter, so it uses `texinfo` facilities to to get the HTML version. It gets split into many small files, using the [mansplit.pl](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/mk/mansplit.pl) script. That does not mean that you cannot do it with `org-publish` (I don't know if you can or not), it just means that the Org mode manual is *not* produced with `org-publish`.

Comment: @NickD thanks for this insight. I will look up the scripts you mention.

Comment: ... I figured out that `org-export` can produce `texinfo` and the `.texi` file can be translated to html files using `makeinfo` (using `--html` option following [instructions](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/html_node/makeinfo-in-Emacs.html#makeinfo-in-Emacs)). In the end, however, my `.texi` file is setting off a bunch of errors upon executing `makeinfo --html`. This is becoming a tangled web of figuring out `texinfo` format and structure, isolating why my org file is not producing a functional `.texi` file, etc. Down the rabbit hole......

Comment: by way of recording what I ended up doing, I switched to `ox-hugo`. It gives me the benefit of exporting subtrees into separate sections and pages. I also found an org-mode gem: the ability to insert TOC of any subtree pretty much anywhere else you'd like (using `#+toc: :target #name-of-custom-link`). Details in the [manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Table-of-Contents.html) -- where else?! :) This TOC insertion and `ox-hugo` ability to convert subtrees into separate pages should help me put together what I want..... hopefully.

Comment: Sounds good - you might want to write it up (concisely) and provide an answer to your own question after you are done.